# Can I make "git gui" pass, say, "--patience" to "git diff"?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-gui

I'm really just looking for a way to configure `git gui` to generate diffs as if by `git diff --patience`, but I strongly suspect that any mechanism which might allow me to do this would allow other options to be passed as well, and so I ask the more general question in the interest of serving posterity better:

> Is there a way to set some `git diff` options that `git gui` should use in generating the diffs it shows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a general way to do this.  There is a particular config option for setting the number of context lines to show (`gui.diffcontext`) but no generic config option to add other arguments to the invocation of `git diff-index`.

However, `git-gui` is written in Tcl, so it's easy to add this option.  If you find `diff.tcl` on your system<sup>*</sup> you can just add the line `lappend cmd --patience` after the line `lappend cmd -p`.

<sup>* <sub>It might be `/usr/share/git-gui/lib/diff.tcl` if you're using a packaged version...</sub></sup>

---

Thanks to Pat Thoyts, the maintainer of `git gui`, for pointing out in the comments below that a `gui.diffopts` option has been now been added to `git gui` so that you can customize the options used for diffs.  (That change was introduced in [this commit](http://repo.or.cz/w/git-gui.git/commitdiff/54531e7c7aeca965c23e60a6805059826a8de75a) but as far as I know is not in a released version of git yet.)

Comment: A patch to do this was committed recently to git-gui so in the future you will be able to add arguments using `gui.diffopts` and edit that on the options page within git-gui.

Comment: @patthoyts: Thank you for pointing that out - I've updated my answer to mention that people can use that option in the future.

Comment: @patthoyts: Yes, and thanks for including it, too! I was quite pleased when I noticed it had been added.

Answer (score 0):

@Mark Longair's answer hinted at it, but here is the full command you can use, with the `--global` flag set because I'm assuming you want this forever throughout, instead of for just the single git-gui instance.

`git config --global gui.diffopts --diff-algorithm=patience`

You could also use any of the following three commands as well if you'd like to try other diff algorithms. https://luppeng.wordpress.com/2020/10/10/when-to-use-each-of-the-git-diff-algorithms/ gives a good visual demonstration of the different results.

- `git config --global gui.diffopts --diff-algorithm=histogram`
- `git config --global gui.diffopts --diff-algorithm=meyer`
- `git config --global gui.diffopts --diff-algorithm=minimal`